# Turn off Paragraph Marks Word 2007

Tags: vba, word-2007

Is there a way to turn off the paragraph marks if they are turned on?

I searched online and did not find anything except ways to check if they are on or off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShowAll` Property is what you're looking for.

To Turn On:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True
```

To Turn Off:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False
```

To Check if Paragraph Marks are on, and to then turn them off:

```
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False
End If
```